# ASP.NET Angular app running on an Nginx proxy not locating static files

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have just created a basic application on Visual Studios and tried to get it running on my Ubuntu server on an Nginx proxy. Once I start it the application runs but the front-end cannot locate the static files and returns a net::ERR_ABORTED on 6 static files listed in [this screen grab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMOdT.png)

My Nginx proxy looks like this:

```
location / {
            # Proxy for dotnet app
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

I have Certbot setup to provide SSL. I'm also not getting any errors in my Nginx error file.

How can I resolve the net::ERR_ABORTED on the static files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the Nginx server couldn't find the files in the root web directory. The following code serves the static files from the specified directory once they are requested...

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
    root   /path/to/static/content;
}
```